# $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} (m-k) = (m-1)m - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k ?$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, summation

I came across the following summation identity that doesn't seem obvious, to me at least, and I am wondering where it comes from and how to derive it? The identity is:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1} (m-k) = (m-1)m - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k ?$$

Comment: Just remark that $\sum (a-b)=\sum a - \sum b$ and that $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}m=m(m-1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(m-k)=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}m-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}k$$
We can bring the $m$ out of the first sum:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(m-k)=m\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}1-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}k$$
and obviously $\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}1=m-1$ (the amount of terms in the sum), so:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(m-k)=m(m-1)-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}k$$

Comment: You type faster than me; great solution.

Answer (score 2):

Please, notice that you can write 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}(m-k)=\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}m-\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}k,
$$
since the sums are finite this is actually straightforward. Then, notice that the first sum the summands are independent of $k$, thus: 
$$
\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}m=m\sum_{k=1}^{m-1}1=m(m-1).
$$
Put these together and get the identity.

Answer (score 2):

Consider:
\begin{align}
S &= \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} (m-k) = (m-1) + (m-2) + \cdots + 2 + 1 \\
&= (m - 1) + (m-2) + \cdots + (m - (m-2)) + (m-(m-1)) \\
&= m \, \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} (1) - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k \\
&= m(m-1) - \sum_{k=1}^{m-1} k.
\end{align}